# Backup SIM message and contact without transfer to phone

Tags: contacts, backup, sim-card

Is it possible to backup the message (e.g. SMS) and contacts inside my SIM card to my external SD Card without transferring them into my Android phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be possible. There are plenty of backup apps available on *Google Play* which allow local backups, such as [SMS Backup & Restore](http://www.appbrain.com/app/SMS-Backup-Restore/com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) or [SMS Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/SMS-Backup/de.stefankarg.smsbackup). For contacts, there's e.g. [Contacts Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Contacts-Backup/com.xuecs.ContactHelper), and for both together [Super Backup : SMS & Contacts](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Super-Backup-SMS-Contacts/com.idea.backup.smscontacts). They all store the backed-up data e.g. on your SDCard.

Though I found no explicit mention of SIM messages, I'd assume they are covered – but you might wish to check for yourself to make sure.

**Update:** As it turned out, above apps do not seem to cover SIM storage. But I've just stumbled upon [Backup2CSV](http://www.appbrain.com/app/backup2csv-pro-backup-to-csv/com.twistedapp.backup2csvfree), which explicitly lists to *Export contact directories (SIM CARD and phone)* (it also lists *Export text messages (SMS)*, but does not explicitly mention the SIM card in that context).

Comment: Tried the apps but they don't read the SIM card message and contacts.

Comment: As *is there an app for X* type questions are off-topic here: Mind to check the playstore for alternatives? I don't know about any on-board solutions.

Comment: Hi, I am not looking for App for X type question but instead, I am looking at ways on how I can backup the message and contact inside my SIM card to the SD Card that I slot inside my Android phone.

Comment: Yes, I know (and I didn't want to accuse you of that!). Trouble is, as there's no native solution I know of, that only leaves looking for apps. So what I was basically saying is: It makes no sense if I pick some apps which *might* do the job ("recommend this and that app"); I can only give you the pointer to check (e.g. search for [backup sms sim](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=backup%20sms%20sim) – oh, [Backup2CSV](http://www.appbrain.com/app/backup2csv-pro-backup-to-csv/com.twistedapp.backup2csvfree) explicitly mentions SIM contacts!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [G Cloud Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.genie9.gcloudbackup) to backup you SMS, Contacts, Call Log, Photos and more to a secure cloud servers.

Comment: Thanks Basbous as you remind me 2 things - One, I forget to insert the word 'to my external SD Card' and Second, you give me another way to backup the SMS and Contacts.

Comment: I am using the G Cloud Backup its amazing product try to use it.