# If I change SIM card, will I lose my memos?

Tags: s-memo

I have a Samsung Galaxy Exhilarate. I have accumulated a lot of memos through the Memo app that came with the phone. I am going to Canada and plan to replace my SIM card with a Canadian SIM card and temporarily buy service from a Canadian provider. Will I continue to have access to the data I've accumulated though the Memo app?

Answer (score 1):

SIM card and application data are not related at all. You can change SIM and the only thing you will lose is contacts and messages stored in the SIM card – if you have them stored on SIM. See this for help [Backup SIM message and contact without transfer to phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/61067/131553)